# How to send some data to other pages when the main page is open?

Tags: ajax

Php is a service program, it can not do a multi threading work. It only show the page after completed all the codes. So I think, whether can send some data to other pages when the main page is open? then process divide in several pages, then return the data back the main page

for example: 
main.php, there has 3 divs.

```
<div id="a">aaa</div>
<div id="b">bbb</div>
<div id="c">ccc</div>
```

How to open the main.php, then automatic send word `aaa` to `a.php`, word `bbb` to `b.php`, word `ccc` to `c.php`?

I prefer ajax can do it. but I search on web, can not find a tutorial which can suit me. Can any one teach me a little? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want multithreading? You can either call a.php from main.php (via require) or you ajax-call a.php via javascript from the loaded page. So what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @Martin, I want do some api json data callback processing, all the code write in one page loading is very slow, so I think whether can send the data to multi pages, process at the same time, then can short the processing time. can you give me some tutorial or simple code about that? thanks.

Comment: Now if your page loading is slow and that's because there is a lot of data being transferred to the browser, try to optimize (compress) the data in your page. But if it's loading slowly because there is much php code being processed, that means your server is just busy, so optimize your php code. I see no need for multithreading here.

Comment: !!! no, that's not what i wanted to show... it really is working for me. however, i will remove it, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing Ajax, are you planning on using only native Javascript, or are you open to a framework?

For example, you can do what you want with [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").load("/aaa.php");
    $("#b").load("/bbb.php");
    $("#c").load("/ccc.php");
});
```

What this does is wait until the DOM is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and then uses [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to call the URL and put the results in each specified div.

To do this without a framework takes a bit more code, but of course you don't have to include the framework then (in case the framework is overkill.